# Adding border to SVG image

Tags: css, svg, border

Is it possible to wrap a SVG image inside a border (that is - putting a border from CSS around that image) .

Comment: Havn't really used svg but i think you can use css rules. Have you tried simply adding it ?µ

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Draw a `<rect>` around the image using `fill="none"`. You can use the `stroke` property to set a border.

Comment: This is the correct answer when it comes to svg:image.

Answer (score 27):

Here are some examples, tested in Firefox:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid black">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>

<br><br>

<svg width="300" height="100" style="border:1px solid black">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(110, 50, 25); stroke-width:4; stroke:rgb(43, 222, 221);" />
</svg>

<br><br>

<svg width="170" height="170" style="border:1px solid black">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="150" height="150" style="fill:blue; stroke:pink; stroke-width:5; fill-opacity:0.1; stroke-opacity:0.9;" />
</svg>
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: very intuitive. tested in Firefox & Chromium

Comment: I like the second option.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add a border to some random geometric SVG shapes from CSS it's possible to do it with `outline` CSS property.

```css
ellipse {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
  >
  <meta
    http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
    content="ie=edge"
  >
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>

<svg width="224" height="112" viewBox="0 0 224 115" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<ellipse cx="112.5" cy="84" rx="28.5" ry="28" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
<path d="M26.5 0L52.9138 45H0.0862255L26.5 0Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
<path d="M196.5 0L202.899 19.3475H223.605L206.853 31.305L213.252 50.6525L196.5 38.695L179.748 50.6525L186.147 31.305L169.395 19.3475H190.101L196.5 0Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
</svg>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solves the problem with CSS, which I think is closer to the spirit of the question.